# Should I pin gem "rails" to a version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, versioning, gemfile

Most rails projects have a very specific version included in their gemfile, right after a `rails new foo`.

For example `gem 'rails', '3.1.3'`

Would it not be better to change this to allow dot-version and e.g. define rails as `gem 'rails', '~>3.2'`?

How is rails version-numbering done? I see major changes between dot-releases, e.g. upgrading from 3.0 to 3.1 requires quite severe changes (mostly to the asset pipeline). How is that for subreleases? Is 3.2.1 a bugfixonly release of 3.2.0?

Comment: you have to see their `release` notes. Its their convention & they stick to their policies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really any reason not to use the `~>` constraint, but you should put:

```
gem 'rails', '~>3.1.3'
```

since that will mean any 3.1.x that is at least 3.1.3. Putting `~>3.1` implies compatibility with any Rails version 3.x.

Rails versioning follows [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/), as far as I know.

However, I think the idea of specifying the exact version is that you read the release notes with every release and make a specific effort to validate that it's okay. Ultimately it's all up to you, though. You should be sure you're somehow following a feed for Rails versions so you always know about security releases either way.